# How to pass an object to the constructor through castle windsor?

Tags: xml, parameters, constructor, castle-windsor, castle

I am building an object through castle windsor and my constructor accepts an argument of a custom type. How do I pass it to my object.

```
public class ArgumentClass
{
   int value1;
   string value2;
}

public interface IInterface
{
}

public class CClass : IInterface
{
   public CClass(ArgumentClass arg) { }
}
```

All my configuration is defined in the XML file and I want to define the argument in the XML as well. So no programming please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I was thinking when I posted this question. Actually I was looking to pass a list of objects to a constructor. I ended up doing it like this:

${id1}
     ${id2}
     ${id3}
     ${id4}

Answer (score 1):

have you looked [at the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Inline-Parameters.ashx)?

Answer (score 1):

I think Hash ask for one of those [usage hint](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-dependencies.ashx)